# Oracle SQL Query for Prioritization logic

Tags: sql, oracle

**Query needs to written for the following:**
***prioritization logic 1 :***
L/M
N/O
**prioritization logic 2 :**
 And if L/M in both id number 1 and idnumber 2 then ID number 1 takes priority
 And if N/O in both id number 1 and idnumber 2 then ID number 1 takes priority
**For eg:**
ID number 1     ID number 2         Expected Output 
L1234589O       L8906565I           L1234589O
N5896812I       L1234353K           L1234353K

Now , I have to written the query

insert into lmno_extract_stg values (case when regexp_like(idnumber1,'^[LMNO][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$', 'i') 
then idnumber1 else idnumber2 end);

This query is not working properly. And taking ID number 1 as priority always.

Please help

Comment: could you please format a little bit your message, it is impossible to understand as it is.

Comment: Done the changes

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: This table : lmno_extract_stg has just 1 column

Comment: you're doing PL/SQL right?

Comment: Basically, i think nobody can help without knowing what is `indx` and `final_load`. you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Yes doing PL/SQL. Changed the Query

Comment: do you understand your regex?

Comment: explain your prioritization logic. Currently, it is gibberish. explain each step, and put example. What does `L/M N/O` means?

Answer (score 1):

if it is giving you id_number1 all the time, it simply means that it matches your regex `'^[LMNO][0-9]{7}[A-Z]$'` each time. check your data.

Your regex means:

1. First letter is L or M or N or O
2. Then you have 7 numbers
3. then one capital letter

Comment: Yes. It gives me 1 data always. Those are sample data which i gave here. But i want an output based on prioritization logic

Comment: In your sample data, all the example match the regex, that is why you receive 1

Comment: so why did you make this regex?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both the ids are columns of a single table ,the query will look like this

```
   select idnum1,idnum2,
          case when substring(idnum1,1,1) = substring (idnum2,1,1) then idnum1 
               when substring(idnum1,1,1) < substring(idnum2,1,1)  then idnum1 
               else idnum2 
               end as idnumber 
    from idnumber ;
```